# Processing xml files and push data to sql table

Tags: sql, xml, ssis

may anyone please help me with this.
How can i parse the below xml to table.

i want data under note to be concatenate and seperated by (;)

for eg:-

App action="A" id="9951" there are two note
Reflector
Packaging Type: Box

so in table under column note it should be (Reflector;Packaging Type: Box)

similarly for qual
all text under need to be semicolon seperated.

xml data

```
DECLARE @DociD INT,
     @XML NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
 '<root><App action="A" id="1">
 <BaseVehicle id="95989"/>
 <EngineBase id="2572"/>
 <Qty>2</Qty>
 <Note>Power</Note>
    <Note>Textured Finish</Note>
    <Note>w/Heat</Note>
    <Note>wo/Turn Signal</Note>
    <Note>w/Puddle Lamps</Note>
    <Note>wo/Dimming</Note>
     <PartType id="11618"/>
 <MfrLabel>Professional Grade</MfrLabel>
 <Position id="23"/>
 <Part>816-8130</Part>
 </App>
 <App action="A" id="2">
 <BaseVehicle id="8198"/>
 <Qty>2</Qty>
 <PartType id="11618"/>
 <MfrLabel>Professional Grade</MfrLabel>
 <Position id="23"/>
 <Part>816-8130</Part>
 </App>
 <App action="A" id="3">
 <BaseVehicle id="8197"/>
 <Qty>2</Qty>
 <PartType id="11618"/>
 <MfrLabel>Professional Grade</MfrLabel>
 <Position id="23"/>
 <Part>816-8130</Part>
 </App>
 <App action="A" id="11840">
    <BaseVehicle id="3723" />
    <Note>Power</Note>
    <Note>Textured Finish</Note>
    <Note>w/Heat</Note>
    <Note>wo/Turn Signal</Note>
    <Note>w/Puddle Lamps</Note>
    <Note>wo/Dimming</Note>
    <Qty>1</Qty>
    <PartType id="13117" />
    <Position id="2" />
    <Part>955-1147</Part>
  </App>
 </root>';

 EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument
     @DociD OUTPUT,
     @XML;

 SELECT  *
 FROM    OPENXML(@DociD,'/root/App',3)
 WITH 
 (appaction CHAR(1) '@action',id INT '@id',
  BaseVehicleID INT './BaseVehicle/@id',
  Note varchar(20) './Note/@id'
  );
```

Table structure

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
    (
[App action] VARCHAR (50),
[APPID] VARCHAR (50),
[BaseVehicleid] VARCHAR (50),
[Qual] VARCHAR (50),
[Qty] VARCHAR (50),
[PartTypeID] VARCHAR (50),
MfrLabel VARCHAR (50),
PositionID VARCHAR (50),
Part VARCHAR (50),
[param value] VARCHAR (50),
SubModelID   VARCHAR (50),
EngineBaseID VARCHAR (50),   
EngineVINID VARCHAR (50),   
RecordCount VARCHAR (50),
Note VARCHAR (50)
)
```

but note column is coming as NULL. Can anyone please suggest.